# JNI GetMethodID of a Java Method that returns a native bytebuffer

Tags: java, android, opencv, java-native-interface

I need to create an opencv::Mat from a native bytebuffer created in Java.  However when I try to get the methodID of the java method that returns the ByteBuffer I get a segfault.  I'm including the onMeshGenerated function as well becuase I have no problems getting and calling that method from JNI.

Java Code:

```
public void onMeshGenerated() {
    mOwner.onMeshGenerated();
}

public ByteBuffer getRGBData() {
    return mOwner.getRGBData();
}
```

JNI Code:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_aquifi_facescan_Scanner3DNativeAPI_Start
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
    javaOnMeshGeneratedMethodRef = env->GetMethodID(cls, "onMeshGenerated", "()V");
    javaOnGetRGBMethodRef = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getRGBData", "()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;");
    // Segfault on the line above
  .
  .
  .

}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That suggests that the *class* wasn't found, which you failed to check.

Comment: if the class wasn't found, which I agree I should check, then why is there no problem with onMeshGenerated, which comes from the same class.

Comment: is there any proguard issue?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you both for your replies.  After uninstalling the app, cleaning the build, and restarting Eclipse it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

To create jobject in JNI module use `NewDirectByteBuffer` .